# Can't traverse into element to scrape rotten tomatoes ratings data using Beautiful Soup and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rotten-tomatoes

I am trying to get to the  element that contains the rating data, but I can't figure out how to traverse into it (image linked below). The span element for both the critic rating and audience rating is in the same class (mop-ratings-wrap__percentage). I tried to get the elements by separately traversing into their respective divs ('mop-ratings-wrap__half' and 'mop-ratings-wrap__half audience-score') but I am getting this error:

```html
runfile('/Users/*/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='/Users/*/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/*/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 22, in <module>
    cr=a.find('span', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__percentage'})

TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments
```

Here is my code:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/*/Downloads/chromedriver")


critics_rating=[]
audience_rating=[]
driver.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/bill_and_ted_face_the_music")

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")

for a in soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__half'}):
      cr=a.find('span', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__percentage'})
      critics_rating.append(cr.text)


for b in soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__half audience-score'}):
      ar=b.find('span', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__percentage'})
      audience_rating.append(ar.text) 

print(critics_rating)
```

I am following this article: https://www.edureka.co/blog/web-scraping-with-python/#demo

[And here is the data I want to extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHRUI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that

```
soup.find()
```

returns a string rather than a bs4 object like you are expecting. Therefore you are calling

```
"somestring".find()
```

which takes no keyword arguments.

(I would comment this but I lack reputation, sorry)

Comment: @Thomas I wanted to up vote your answer so that you can use your comment privilege , however i can not as its little misleading( Voted another question of you, now you can comment anywhere ).  You are right find returns a string, but its a HTML format and if it forms a string for webelement, we can use find method on top of returned element. The reason we for issue here is because he tries to loop through element returned which will make it traverse through each letter of return string  which is no more constitute a webelement. See the Answer i have tried to explain issue and give solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your loop  `for a in soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__half'}):` you have returned one single element and then try to traverse through it, which is making equivalent to traversing through each letter of returned string element. Now you can not run `find` method on letters. **Solution** If you want to loop through element(s) to use `find` method on top of them, use `find_all` instead. As it will return a list of `webelements`, which you can traverse one by one using loop.

```
    content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
ratings =[]
for a in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__half'}):
      cr=a.find('span', attrs={'class':'mop-ratings-wrap__percentage'})
      ratings.append(cr.text)

for rating in ratings:
    print(rating.replace("\n", "").strip())
```

**Output:** Above code will print :

[image]

**Note :** To print your desired result, above is not the most shopiscated way of doing. But i have tried to answer your doubt rather than giving a better solution. You can use `ratings[0]` to print critic rating and `ratings[1]` to print user rating.

Comment: Thanks so much, this works. The thing is, I only want '81%' returned, as that's the critic rating. '75%' is the audience rating. The issue is that they are both contained in elements that are classified identically. To that end, do you know of a better way to access that element? Thanks

Comment: you have already created a list you can just traverse it to get both rating(See solution). Alternative is used a locator which only match critic rating.

Comment: Great, thank you. How do I modify the second loop so the clean values are saved to ratings instead of just printed to the loop?\